# React: Access child element with findDOMNode throws error

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Container` component, it gets a few children.

on `componentDidUpdate` i would like to change a style attribute.

seems like the Container should be able to handle this, instead of each child handling itself.

Problem, react throws an error when trying to get Dom node of child.

```
  var childA = this.props.children[0];
  React.findDOMNode(childA);
  => Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode (keys: )
```

---

**EDIT:** That ^^^ was the **wrong way** to write react!

> If your children need to do something, you should always try to pass it down from the top.

lets say you have 3 colors: `green,red,blue` and you want your children to be colored that way, but maybe they change order often. pass it down

```
Parent = React.createClass({
  renderChildren: function(){
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]

    return React.Children.map(this.props,children, function(child, index){
      // this returns a legit clone, adding one extra prop. 
      return React.cloneElement(child, {color: colors[index]});
    })
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>{this.renderChildren()}</div>
    )
  }
})

Child = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (<div style={{background: this.props.color}}>{'YOLO'}</div>)
  }
})
```

Comment: jsfiddle reproduction https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/19983/

Comment: this is your case: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4244

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not a recommended practice when working with React. Don't modify the DOM yourself, use `state` and `props`.

Children components:

```
var ChildrenA = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div style={{color: this.props.color}}>Hello A</div>;
    }
});
```

App:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
          <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
          <div>
            <Container/>
          </div>
        </div>);
    }
});
```

Container:

```
var Container = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {color: "red"}
    },
    toggle: function(){
      this.setState({
        color: this.state.color == "red" ? "blue" : "red"
       })
    },
    render: function() {
        return (<div onClick={this.toggle}>
             <ChildrenA color={this.state.color}/>
             <ChildrenB/>
        </div>);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3m8wLcgk/

You might want to check this out: [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: hmmm. heres a rough example: my parent contains 10 children, only 1 is "active" at a time. seems reasonable to have the parent 'display: block" on the one that is active and have the others be display:none;